# How to exclude particular files from being copied by rsync?

Tags: macos, rsync, osx-mavericks

I am reading [rsync docs](http://rsync.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html), INCLUDE/EXCLUDE PATTERN RULES section. Following the rules explained there I would like to exclude the following folders and files:

- all *.metadata* folders
- all *.DS_Store* files

So, I am creating rules like:

- `- .DS_Store`
- `.metadata/`

But files and folders are not excluded. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Btw. mentioning the whole command line you're using would be quite helpful for determining what, if any, is your error (my guess for something which should help, though, is put below).

Answer (score 0):

The following will skip everything in `.DS_Store` directories plus the `.DS_Store` directories themselves and works with rsync distributed with Mavericks: `rsync --exclude='.DS_Store' --exclude='.metadata' <your_source_dir> <your_destination_dir>`.

The `--exclude=<pattern>` is actually just a shorthard for `--filter='- <pattern>'`. This means `--exclude='.DS_Store'` and `--filter='- .DS_Store'` are equivalent. The same goes with `--include=<pattern>` which is actually just a shorthand for `--filter='+ <pattern>'`.